# Firebase get auth token through REST?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, facebook-c#-sdk, unity-webgl

I'm trying to integrate Firebase into a Unity WebGL app, unlike iOS and Android there's no official Firebase plugin for it.

I'd like to try and use the Unity [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class to make web requests to endpoints to do firebase authentication.

Is there an endpoint I can call passing the username and password to firebase that will return an auth token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be a massive security hole for the end user who gives up their password to you.  Users should only be typing passwords directly into the site that controls their account.

You should probably take a look into calling through to JavaScript to use the Firebase web SDKs.

[WebGL: Interacting with browser scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

Comment: Yep I thought it would be, I'll give that a look thanks for the link :)

Comment: The main thing to avoid would be spoofing a different application/website.  As long as your app is associated with their login, there shouldn't be a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Firebase Auth has a REST API that sends the email/password combo (as POST parameters) in an https call.

[Firebase Auth REST API Sign in with email / password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password)